# I couldn't install f.lux

Tags: f.lux

I followed their install routine on their website, but step three in the cmd won't work. Has anyone got any luck in installing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Flux wasn't updated for the recent Ubuntu versions. The other way to use Flux is through the xflux daemon mentioned on the site. Download the .tgz file from the site and run that. You can copy that to /usr/bin directory. After that just run

```
xflux -l latitude -g longitude
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried installing f.lux yet because it's closed source software. I'm not sure if you are aware but there's an open-source, linux friendly, alternative, which is **redshift**.

More info here:

- [Redshift Configuration and use | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift)
- [Redshift | jonls.dk Blog](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)

Comment: I apologize if you're not interested in an alternative and trully want flux.

Comment: I'm using it, but this one doesn't switch automatically day to night and I seem to forget about doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

It works for me in Xubuntu 16.04.